# C Segmentation fault upon entering a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with entering a function (in C), it will give a segmentation fault when I try to enter `calc_uq()` from the function `dynamical_matrix()`. When I try to compile it, it will still print `check5`, but it will give a segmentation fault before printing `checkA`.

This problem only occurs to me with I choose a large amount of `timesteps` (steps=100000), for `steps=75000` it still works.

Below is part of my code, the main function, the `dynamical_matrix()` function and the `calc_uq()` function.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <complex.h>

#define MAX 1000 //max aantal deeltjes
#define NDIM 3
#define npart 108
#define steps 100000 
#define kint 1
//d is distance squared  

int s=20000; //calculations start at time = s.
double pi=3.14159265359;
double radius=0.5;
double r2[npart][NDIM];
double r[steps][npart][NDIM], R[steps][npart][NDIM], RC[steps][npart][NDIM]; //r is with periodic boundary, R without, RC = R-CoM
double CoM[steps][NDIM];
double box;

double mean[npart][NDIM];
double complex uq[steps][NDIM];
double complex Dq[3][3];
double ui[steps][npart][NDIM];
double sqrtN,beta=1;
double k[3];

main()
{ 
  int i,p,t=0;
  readparts();
  init_random_seed();

  sqrtN=sqrt(npart);
  k[0]=1*(2*pi/box)*(kint);
  k[1]=0*(2*pi/box)*(kint);
  k[2]=0*(2*pi/box)*(kint);

  for(i=0;i<npart;i++)
  {
    r[t][i][0]=r2[i][0];
    r[t][i][1]=r2[i][1];
    r[t][i][2]=r2[i][2];
  }
  t++;
  writedata();

  for(p=1;p<steps*100;p++)
  {
    random_particle_displacement(); 
    if(p%100==0)
    {

      for(i=0;i<npart;i++)
      {
    r[t][i][0]=r2[i][0];
    r[t][i][1]=r2[i][1];
    r[t][i][2]=r2[i][2];
      }
     if((t+1)%1000==0){printf("t=%d\n",(t+1));}
     t++;
    }
    if(p%1000==0){writedata();}
  }    
  printf("check1\n");
  dynamical_matrix();
  print_Dq();
  print_R72();
  print_uq();
}

calc_uq()
{
  printf("checkA\n");
  double complex arg[npart];
  double complex sum[steps][NDIM];
  int i,t;

  printf("check6\n");

  for(i=0;i<npart;i++)
  {
    arg[i]=I * ( k[0]*mean[i][0] + k[1]*mean[i][1] + k[2]*mean[i][2] );
    printf("arg[%d]=%fI\tmean[%d][0]=%f\tmean[%d][1]=%f\tmean[%d][2]=%f\n",i,cimag(arg[i]),i,mean[i][0],i,mean[i][1],i,mean[i][2]);
  }

  printf("check7\n");

  for(t=0;t<steps;t++)
  {

    sum[t][0]=0;
    sum[t][1]=0;
    sum[t][2]=0;  

    for(i=0;i<npart;i++) //calculate the Fourier sum.
    {
      ui[t][i][0]=RC[t][i][0]-mean[i][0]; //calculate the displacement from its mean position
      ui[t][i][1]=RC[t][i][1]-mean[i][1];
      ui[t][i][2]=RC[t][i][2]-mean[i][2];

      sum[t][0]+=cexp(arg[i])*ui[t][i][0];
      sum[t][1]+=cexp(arg[i])*ui[t][i][1];
      sum[t][2]+=cexp(arg[i])*ui[t][i][2];
    }

    uq[t][0] = sum[t][0]/sqrtN; //uq at timestep t
    uq[t][1] = sum[t][1]/sqrtN;
    uq[t][2] = sum[t][2]/sqrtN;
  }
   printf("check8\n");
}


dynamical_matrix()
{
  printf("check2\n");
  double complex uquq[steps][NDIM];

  double complex uquqmean[3][3];

  printf("check3\n");

  int i,j,t;

  calc_R();
  calc_CoM();
  calc_RC();

  printf("check4\n");

  for(i=0;i<npart;i++)
  {
    calc_mean_pos(i);   
  }

  printf("check5\n");

  calc_uq();      

  //calculate <uq*.uq> 
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
      uquqmean[i][j]=calc_uquqmean(i,j);
      Dq[i][j]=1/(beta*uquqmean[i][j]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you about the program? And if it *doesn't* tell you anything, get a better compiler.

Comment: [TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read). Please try to narrow it down, for example only show the code that crashes, and that calls the functions. Include values of variables and arguments as well. Preferably try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And please run in a debugger to actually pinpoint the location of the crash in your code, and check the values of all involved variables.

Comment: Probably you cause stack overflow. Typically compilers default to 1MB or 2MB of allowed space for all the local variables in the program.  `double complex sum[steps][NDIM]` may be over 4MB by itself. To fix this switch to either static or dynamic allocation for the large local arrays; or configure your OS for larger stack.

Comment: Also, I doubt the *compiler* will say "check5", but your program when *running* it might do that.

Comment: @M.M it was indeed the allowed space for the local variables. I solved it by just making it a global variable, not the most neat solution, but it did work. Thanks!